# initWithNibName : I have no scroll and no navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, interface-builder

So I've a button with a IBAction heading to another ViewController by its initWithNibName method. Everything is embedded in a NavigationController.

I also created a .xib for this ViewController, here is a quick screenshot :

[image]

Here is my code :

.h

```
@interface ModeEmploiController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UITextView *vueOffres, *vueInfos, *vueGrilles;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

.m

```
@implementation ModeEmploiController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 529)];
        // Here I define vueOffres, vueInfos and vueGrilles and for each of them :
        [self.view addSubview:vueGrilles/vueInfos/vueOffres];
    }
}
```

But when I run my app, my scroll isn't enabled and I don't have the navigation bar of my navigation controller. What's happening?

Comment: How do you init your navigation controller?

Comment: In fact I just added it and made it embed in my view controller in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `ModeEmploiController` from `xib`, but keep its child `View` and `ScrollView`.

now click on `File's Owner` and put `ModeEmploiController` from Identity inspector in right panel.

Now right click on `File's Owner` and connect property of `view` to `View` and `scrollView` to `ScrollView`.

Comment: is your content's Size actually of 320, 529? and I don't see any child view inside your ScrollView, are adding it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

add another view inside the `ScrollView` i called mine content view. the do

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
```

for the navigation bar you need to have a uinavigation controller and make your controller the rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller. like this

```
-(IBAction)MyButton:(id)sender
{
    MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization code is in the wrong method.

Since you are using Storyboards, your view controller is being unarchived from a nib file. The correct place to initialize the controls is in the `awakeFromNib` method.

Make sure that you have set up an IBOutlet property for your scroll view and hooked it up in the Storyboard, and then:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 529)];
    // Here I define vueOffres, vueInfos and vueGrilles and for each of them :
    [self.view addSubview:vueGrilles/vueInfos/vueOffres];
}
```

That just leaves the problem of the subview that you are adding. What is `vueGrilles/vueInfos/vueOffres`? You should create this view properly within the `viewDidLoad` method and add it as a subview there instead of in this initialiser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it still doesn't enable the scrolling.